# How do I sudo environment?

Tags: php, exec, environment, sudo, spamassassin

I am using spamassassin in a php script, but when I train spamassassin as my user the php script's exec command to call spamassassin get the untrained version because of the user specific nature of sa-learn. So I need to sudo to my user in the exec command and get the environment of my user along with the premissions

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -u <username> <command> ...
```

Comment: Tried that uses the prefence files of the users calling sudo not the user in sudo

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -H -u <username> <command>
```

The -H flag sets the `$HOME` environment variable.  Without setting this flag, SpamAssassin is probably looking in the old user's homedir for settings.